# Есть ли альтернативы методу filter у массива объектов JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, фильтры

Есть примерно такой массив объектов:

```
const arr = [
  { flag: "Y", status: "Активна", name: "a" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Активна", name: "b" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Отмена", name: "c" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Закрыта", name: "d" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Закрыта", name: "e" },
];
```

1. Нужно получить два массива, в первый попадают значения, которые одновременно имеют `flag === "Y"` и `status === "Активна"`, а второй - все остальные значение, которые **ОДНОВРЕМЕННО** `flag !== "Y"` и `status !== "Активна"`.
   То есть, если flag === "Y", то status === "Отмена" или "Закрыта". И наоборот status === "Активна", то flag === "N"

   Я делаю через фильтр

   ```
   arr.filter(task => task.flag === "Y" && task.status === "Активна")

   arr.filter(task => !(task.flag === "Y" && task.status === "Активна"))
   ```

   Вопрос: Какие еще есть варианты получить два отдельных массива, может быть еще более простые или фильтр тут хорош (и чем  )
2. Хочу разобраться, до конца не совсем пойму - почему результат этого выражения

   ```
   arr.filter(task => (task.flag !== "Y") && (task.status !== "Активна"))
   ```

   отличается от

   ```
   arr.filter(task => !(task.flag === "Y" && task.status === "Активна"))
   ```

Comment: Ну можно например процедурным циклом (`for`|`for..of`), либо через `reduce` в два массива с последующей деструктуризацией результата в две переменные. А почему результат логических выражений различается - потому что логика у них разная (хз как еще можно объяснить очевидное).

Comment: В задаче противоречащие друг другу условия: _«все остальные»_, и _«которые ОДНОВРЕМЕННО `flag !== "Y"` и `status !== "Активна"`»_ - это не одно и то же. Определись, какой из этих вариантов условий для второго массива верен, а какой ложный. Ответ пока что дан исходя из предположения что верен второй вариант условий (т.к. он более однозначно расписан).

Answer (score 2):

##### Альтернативы двум проходам методом `filter`

- Заполнение массивов в процедурном цикле:

```js
const arr = [
  { flag: "Y", status: "Активна", name: "a" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Активна", name: "b" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Отмена", name: "c" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Закрыта", name: "d" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Закрыта", name: "e" },
];

const foo = [],
      bar = [];
for (const itm of arr) {
  if ((itm.flag === 'Y') && (itm.status === 'Активна'))
    foo.push(itm);
  else if ((itm.flag !== 'Y') && (itm.status !== 'Активна'))
    bar.push(itm);
}

console.log('foo:', foo, '\n', 'bar:', bar);
```

- Деструктурирующее присваивание результата `reduce` (редьюс в двумерный массив):

```js
const arr = [
  { flag: "Y", status: "Активна", name: "a" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Активна", name: "b" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Отмена", name: "c" },
  { flag: "N", status: "Закрыта", name: "d" },
  { flag: "Y", status: "Закрыта", name: "e" },
];

const [foo, bar] = arr.reduce((rslt, itm) => {
  if ((itm.flag === 'Y') && (itm.status === 'Активна'))
    rslt[0].push(itm);
  else if ((itm.flag !== 'Y') && (itm.status !== 'Активна'))
    rslt[1].push(itm);
  return rslt;
}, [[], []]);

console.log('foo:', foo, '\n', 'bar:', bar);
```

---

Так как задачей определены свои условия для попадания в каждый из массивов - требуется выполнять две проверки.
Если бы во второй массив действительно попадали "все остальные значения", то есть безусловно (что задача исключает, наличием условий для второго массива) - то можно было бы обойтись без второй проверки: используя `else` или третий блок тернарного оператора.